# I am using Firebase and I got this Exception when create the firebase object

Tags: android, firebase

this the logcat message

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy:()V from class com.firebase.client.utilities.DefaultRunLoop
      at com.firebase.client.utilities.DefaultRunLoop.<init>(DefaultRunLoop.java:45)
      at com.firebase.client.android.AndroidPlatform$1.<init>(AndroidPlatform.java:44)
      at com.firebase.client.android.AndroidPlatform.newRunLoop(AndroidPlatform.java:44)
      at com.firebase.client.core.Context.ensureRunLoop(Context.java:224)
      at com.firebase.client.core.Context.initServices(Context.java:111)
      at com.firebase.client.core.Context.freeze(Context.java:92)
      at com.firebase.client.core.RepoManager.getLocalRepo(RepoManager.java:55)
      at com.firebase.client.core.RepoManager.getRepo(RepoManager.java:19)
      at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:172)
      at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:177)
      at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:155)
      at elnagga.forebasedemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522717/android-app-is-crashing-when-connecting-to-firebase/35528810#35528810

Comment: I am sorry man you right but i put the exception in google and nothing showed but I learn a little something from here tow
next time i will search directly in stackoverflow Thanks

Comment: Thanks very much for documenting this here.  This crash was occurring for me too and couldn't find any other info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Android App is crashing when connecting to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522717/android-app-is-crashing-when-connecting-to-firebase). This appears to be a bug in the firebase android client. To avoid this Error use firebase android client version `2.5.0` instead of `2.5.1` which I assume you are using now.

Comment: Thanks I tried 2.5.0 and 2.5.2 and them both worked fine

Comment: I had the same crash occurring and downloaded the 2.5.0 and it fixed mine also.  Thanks for documenting here.